# Why is Python Installation in "Library" directory macOS?

Tags: python, macos, python-install

I'm on a new Mac and installing Python. I believe I reinstalled my Python using Homebrew. The path, however, is unusual to me, and I'm wondering why it is located here:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3`

I'm used to Python being somewhere like this, instead (which is *also* is):

`/Users/user.name/Library/Python/3.9/bin`

What is different about the first installation? Are there any special considerations if my Python is located here?

Comment: The `/Library/...` location is where the official Python distribution installer (not Homebrew) installs Python. There's nothing wrong, that's just the default path for frameworks on macOS. Homebrew would install under `/usr` if you use the defaults.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.x/bin/python3` is the Python distribution shipped with macOS.

It's usually a good practice to create your own Python environment for your projects instead of using the default Python installation (consider reading about [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)).

If you want to use your Homebrew installation, run `brew info python` to find your Python installation path, then append the parent directory's path to your PATH variable by editing `~/.zshrc` (assuming you're using zsh, the default shell).

```sh
$ brew info python
....
Python has been installed as
  /opt/homebrew/bin/python3
...
```

```
# inside ~/.zshrc
...
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"
....
```

Comment: And I'm noticing in particular that you're appending to the *beginning* of PATH to ensure that this installation gets picked up before the default Python 3 installation.